# Using array from a job as matrix in another job

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

Here is my workflow

```
name: Identify Changed Files and Directories

on: [push]

jobs:
  identify-changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs: 
      matrix: ${{ steps.extract.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Fetch history
        run: git fetch origin

      - name: Git Diff
        uses: technote-space/get-diff-action@v6
        with:
          PATTERNS: |
            **/*.js
            **/*/*.js
            **/Dockerfile

      - name: Extract Dockerfile paths
        id: extract
        run: |
          dockerfile_matrix=()

          # Remove single quotes
          cleaned_string=$(echo "$GIT_DIFF_FILTERED" | sed "s/'//g")

          # Split by space
          IFS=' ' read -ra substrings <<< "$cleaned_string"

          # Loop through substrings
          for substring in "${substrings[@]}"; do
              # Split by / and take the first occurrence
              IFS='/' read -ra parts <<< "$substring"
              root_directory="${parts[0]}"

              # Search for Dockerfile in the root_directory and add to dockerfile_matrix if found
              DOCKERFILE=$(find "$root_directory" -type f -name "Dockerfile")
              if [[ ! -z "$DOCKERFILE" ]]; then
                  dockerfile_matrix+=("$DOCKERFILE")
              fi
          done

          # Convert dockerfile_matrix to a JSON array
          json_array=()
          for dockerfile in "${dockerfile_matrix[@]}"; do
              json_array+=("'${dockerfile}'")
          done

          # Convert the json_array to a string with brackets and comma-separated values
          json_array_str="[$(IFS=,; echo "${dockerfile_matrix[*]}")]"

          # Save JSON array to output
          echo "matrix=$json_array_str" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo $json_array_str

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: identify-changes
    continue-on-error : true

    strategy:
      matrix:
        dockerfile: ${{ needs.identify-changes.outputs.matrix }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build Docker images
        run: |
          echo ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
```

I'm creating an array in my first job and I want to use it as a matrix in the second job.
When I'm using the github actions syntax I get an error:

```
Identify Changed Files and Directories: .github#L1
Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'build'. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 69, Col: 21): Unexpected value '[Directory1/Dockerfile]'
```

If I hardcode the array [Directory1/Dockerfile, Directory2/Dockerfile, ...] it works properly.
I don't understand where it's going wrong.

Comment: Did you try using the [fromJSON()](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function? Like this: `dockerfile: ${{ fromJSON(needs.identify-changes.outputs.matrix) }}`

Comment: @GuiFalourd 

`Identify Changed Files and Directories: .github#L1
Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'build'. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 69, Col: 21): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 69, Col: 21): Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: S. Path '', line 1, position 2.,.github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 69, Col: 21): Unexpected value '' `

Comment: In that case, it seems the `$json_array_str` variable may not be correctly built, as the function isn't able to parse it. Could you add in the question the printed result from the `echo $json_array_str` step?

Comment: result of echo $json_array_str : ['directory1/Dockerfile','directory2/Dockerfile']

Comment: I simplified the workflow to create the JSON [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester86.yml) and it seems [to work as expected](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/6084293883), with the `$json_array_str` you shared.